# When flashing a custom ROM, why do I get an error on getprop("ro.product.device")?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

Whenever I try to flash a ROM on my ASUS Transformer Prime (tf201), I get the following error:

```
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "tf201" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "tf201"
```

I've got around it by opening the ZIP file of the ROM, navigating to `/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` and just removing this check. The ROM installs fine then.

But still I'm left with the question: why isn't my device recognized as a tf201, while it obviously is? Is it because I formatted the `system` partition in a format frenzy?

Comment: I had the same thing on a Vodacom branded Galaxy Tab4 10.1, I believe they either did it by mistake when changing another model's ROM and forgetting to update the device id, or intentionally to make the flashing or custom ROM installation a bit harder.

Comment: I had the same problem, because my device was unrooted after a factory reset and TWRP didn't have permission to read /system/build.prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that your `build.prop` in the /SYSTEM folder is configured correctly and has the variable `ro.product.device` set, often time in custom ROMs the build.prop is not configured completely and some of these variables are necessary for certain functionality checks. You can open it up in a text editor and look for it and make sure it is set and there are no bad characters in there that might affect it being parsed properly.

Also check these variables and make sure they are set as well, it is good to have them:

- ro.product.model=XXX
- ro.product.brand=XXX
- ro.product.name=XXX
- ro.product.device=XXX
- ro.product.board=XXX
- ro.product.manufacturer=XXX

Answer (score 4):

This could be caused by a variety of reasons, the primary reason being an incompatible recovery, where the appropriate variables aren't correctly set. Try using another recovery (example: TWRP) , and see if you're getting this error.

A temporary solution for this would be:

You could just open up the zip file, extract the

> META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script

file, and remove the getprop lines, which look like:

> getprop(xyz) == "xyzyxz");

lines from it. These lines are usually in the beginning of the updater-script file.

As you say that the ROM is "for" your device, this should cause no problems.

Then, just drag-drop back the updater-script file, back into the zip. Now, flashing wouldn't be causing any problems.

Note that:

Use programs like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), or [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/), while extracting the updater-script file.
Use the [Notepad++ text-editor](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), or alternatives like [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), which support the Linux EOL formats.

Comment: **Beware:** While removing that check *in this specific context* is fine, you shouldn't do that light-hearted; the check is there for a good reason. If you do so, you must be ***absolutely sure*** the ROM is compatible with your device. If it's not, you might get into serious trouble and even (soft-) brick your device. // @Vineeth: Not a critique, your answer is perfectly fine in the context. I would include that warning nevertheless for those "quick-readers" ;)

Comment: Also, to complement @Izzy's comment, you should not be just updating the `updater-script` and re-packing it back into the archive, because that zip file is signed upon generation of the *initial* `update.zip`. And because of the change in the zip file as result, the SHA256 checksums ***will*** not match, will spell disaster. The SHA256 checksum is reported and contained within the zip file itself, if recovery was to check it will flag up, possibly throwing up an error message or refusing to process it.

Comment: For me, updating the recovery to the latest version solved this issue. I think this should be the first course of action before modifying the setup script.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, I DEFINITELY had a 'matisselte' (TAB4 10.1 SM-T535) device, but I think the network operator (Vodacom) who branded it made a mistake and set the variable to be `matissewifi` which it definitely was not. I made the first line of the `/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` file to match my model, and I installed the correct ROM (matisselte), and it worked.